# Are struct in c++ similar to enum or classes?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if a `struct` has the same idea as `enum` in c++? If someone can explain similarities/differences I will be grateful I am trying to learn.

Comment: Note that `enum` doesn't create its own scope, unless you use `enum class`.

Comment: @chris yep, major PIA in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

struct is basically a class with all members public.

For instance:

```
struct MyNewStruct {
    int myNewInt;
    double myNewDouble;
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
class MyNewClass {
public:
    int myNewInt;
    double myNewDouble;
};
```

Hence, you can create a struct with constructor:

```
struct MyNewStruct {
    int myNewInt;
    double myNewDouble;

    MyNewStruct(int i, double d) 
    : myNewInt(i), myNewDouble(d)
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 8):

> Are struct in c++ similar to enum or classes?

In C++, a struct is essentially the same as a class, except that the default access modifiers  for member variables, methods, and for base classes are all public, where in a class, the default access modifier is private.

Answer (score 1):

An enum is for abstracting away magic numbers.

A struct is for holding a collection of different variables.

You can almost think of an enum as a stand-in for an int or char to make things more readable.

Comment: This is very vague. Classes in C++ should ideally *also* be alongside int and char (i.e. they should behave like built-in types), and the special status of an enum as a constrained type on ints in the C++ type taxonomy isn’t actually entirely clear.